# Trying to create basic automation and chrome driver is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I work in intellij idea software

Comment: Please specify your question

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

If you using junit 5. It's as easy as using the about code to set up chrome and you ready to go.

Here is the url to Bonigarcia's github account to see the implementation. https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/README.md#basic-usage